# Using LightGBM with MultiOutput Regressor and eval set

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, lightgbm

I am trying to use LightGBM as a multi-output predictor as suggested [here](https://www.kaggle.com/hireme/two-outputs-regressor-with-lightgbm). I am trying to forecast values for thirty consecutive days. I have a panel dataset so I can't use the traditional time series approaches.

I have a very large dataset so it takes too long to train the model without early stopping. So, I am trying to pass the `eval_set`, `early_stopping_rounds` and `eval_metric` parameters like below:

```py
from lightgbm import LGBMRegressor
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor

hyper_params = {
    'task': 'train',
    'boosting_type': 'gbdt',
    'objective': 'regression',
    'metric': ['l1','l2'],
    'learning_rate': 0.01,
    'feature_fraction': 0.9,
    'bagging_fraction': 0.7,
    'bagging_freq': 10,
    'verbose': 0,
    "max_depth": 8,
    "num_leaves": 128,  
    "max_bin": 512,
    "num_iterations": 10000
}

lgbc_fit_params = { 
    'early_stopping_rounds' : 300,
    'eval_set': (X_test, y_test_array),
    'eval_metric':'l1'
}

gbm = lgb.LGBMRegressor(**hyper_params)
regr_multiglb = MultiOutputRegressor(gbm)
regr_multiglb.fit(X_train, y_train_array, **lgbc_fit_params)
```

Here, both `y_train_array` and `y_test_array`  are 2-d numpy arrays with shapes `(1953395, 30)` and `(331003, 30)`, respectively.

When I run this code, I get the following error:

[image: Error message]

When I run the fit function without `**lgbc_fit_parameters`, the code runs without errors.

Any suggestions on how to pass the base estimator's (LightGBM) fit parameters into the wrapper?

Comment: Please do not post images of error messages without also posting the text of the error messages, as that makes it unlikely that others will find this question from search engines. Please also provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That should include details like the versions of `lightgbm`, `scikit-learn`, and Python you're using.

Answer (score 0):

it's clearly show in the error photo your label mean y_test and y_test are in the form of list,1-D array or panda series but you gave a multi-dimension array